# Download M total files with N simultaneous Async HTTP clients, where M is large and N is configurable

Tags: perl, http, asynchronous, anyevent, worker-pool

I'm trying to write a script which will download at most `N` files simultaneously via HTTP.

I've previously used [AnyEvent::Worker::Pool](http://search.cpan.org/~mons/AnyEvent-Worker-0.06/lib/AnyEvent/Worker/Pool.pm) to manage a pool of BLOCKING tasks. I've also used [AnyEvent::HTTP](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/AnyEvent-HTTP-2.15/HTTP.pm) in combination with [AnyEvent->condvar](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/AnyEvent-7.05/lib/AnyEvent.pm#CONDITION_VARIABLES) to manage NON-BLOCKING downloads individually.

I thought that it should be pretty simple to combine the two approaches so that [AnyEvent->condvar](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/AnyEvent-7.05/lib/AnyEvent.pm#CONDITION_VARIABLES) makes AnyEvent::HTTP::http_get look BLOCKING from the perspective of [AnyEvent::Worker::Pool](http://search.cpan.org/~mons/AnyEvent-Worker-0.06/lib/AnyEvent/Worker/Pool.pm).

However, I'm getting some errors I don't understand, presumably due to implementation details of [AnyEvent::Worker](http://search.cpan.org/~mons/AnyEvent-Worker-0.06/lib/AnyEvent/Worker.pm). Here's a really cut-down version of the script that demonstrates the issue:

```
use EV;
use AnyEvent 5;
use AnyEvent::Worker::Pool;
use AnyEvent::HTTP;
use 5.10.0;
use strict;

my $pool_size = 2;
my $num_jobs  = 7;

# Create a pool of $pool_size workers
my $workers = AnyEvent::Worker::Pool->new($pool_size, sub {
  my ($job) = @_;
  eval {
    my $cv = AnyEvent->condvar;
    print "worker starting download [$job] ...\n";
    http_get 'http://download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip', sub {
      my ($data, $headers) = @_;
      if ($headers->{Status} =~ /^2/) { 
        print "download [$job] succeeded.\n"; 
      } else { 
        print "download [$job] failed.\n"; 
      }
      $cv->send; # notification of download complete/exit.
    };

    $cv->recv; # wait for download to complete/exit before returning to pool
  }; if ($@) {
    print "worker payload error: $@\n";
  }
  return 1;
});

# dispatch the full list of downloads
my ($need,$done) = ($num_jobs, 0);
for my $job (0 .. ($need - 1)) {
  print "dispatching job $job...\n";
  $workers->do($job, sub {
    print "worker [$job] payload threw exception: $@\n" if $@;
    print "worker [$job] payload completed successfully!\n" unless $@;
    EV::unloop if ++$done == $need;
  });
}

EV::loop; # wait here for all downloads to complete
print "We're done!\n"; # some useful code to follow here...
```

Demo output is as follows:

```
user@host:~$ ./test.pl
dispatching job 0...
dispatching job 1...
dispatching job 2...
dispatching job 3...
dispatching job 4...
dispatching job 5...
dispatching job 6...
worker starting download [0] ...
worker starting download [1] ...
EV: error in callback (ignoring): unexpected eof at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/AnyEvent/Worker/Pool.pm, line 46
EV: error in callback (ignoring): unexpected eof at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/AnyEvent/Worker/Pool.pm, line 46
EV: error in callback (ignoring): unexpected eof at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/AnyEvent/Worker/Pool.pm, line 46
worker [6] payload threw exception: no worker connection
EV: error in callback (ignoring): no worker connection at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/AnyEvent/Worker/Pool.pm, line 60

^C
user@host:~$
user@host:~$
user@host:~$ download [1] failed.
unable to write results: Broken pipe at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/AnyEvent/Worker.pm line 139.
  ...caught at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/AnyEvent/Worker.pm line 145.
```

Why [AnyEvent::HTTP](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/AnyEvent-HTTP-2.15/HTTP.pm)?

In my real script I'm using many more features of `AnyEvent::HTTP`; particularly, I'm combining the `on_body` callback with `Term::StatusBar` to show a progress bar for the end-user of the script; additionally, I'm strategically 'pausing' in the `on_body` callback such that I maintain a transfer rate equal to or less than a rate pre-defined by the end-user.

Please feel free to suggest an alternative with those features (or an easy way to hack them in!)

Why [AnyEvent::Worker::Pool](http://search.cpan.org/~mons/AnyEvent-Worker-0.06/lib/AnyEvent/Worker/Pool.pm)?

I was familiar with it already. Alternative suggestions welcome.

Why [EV](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/EV-4.15/EV.pm)?

It's fast. Again, alternatives suggestions welcome.

Comment: Perl scripts tend to use global variables for filehandles. This isn't threadsafe.

Comment: @DavidKnipe I don't think that `EV` nor `AnyEvent` nor `AnyEvent::HTTP` use perl threads. Do you have some evidence that they do?

Comment: No, I'm not at all familiar with the libraries you're using, but the question sounded thread-related. Basically don't pay too much attention to me :-)

Comment: @DavidKnipe. No problem :-) `AnyEvent` is an implementation agnostic event-loop abstraction. In this case I'm using `EV` (libev) which is an event-loop based on a single-threaded event multiplexing paradigm.

Comment: Are you saying that the clients take it in turns to handle bits of response from the server? In that case it's still true that they're all trying to have open filehandles at the same time. Which would be problematic. That's assuming that they use filehandles, and that the filehandles are implemented in the traditional style as global variables. And rather unhelpfully, Perl doesn't seem to complain if you try to open a filehandle that's already open. But that's Perl for you :-)

Comment: @DavidKnipe the clients work fine simultaneously... this isn't 1995 :) These single thread event-based servers/loops are widely used in Perl now for about 10 years. I'm simply trying to manage the workers in a pool of `N` MAX workers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use AnyEvent::Worker::Poll for this task.
And I'll recommend you do not use loop specific features like EV::loop EV::unloop. This makes your code incompatible with other loops implementation.

Your code may be rewrited like this

```
use strict;
use AnyEvent;
use AnyEvent::HTTP;

my $pool_size = 2;
my $num_jobs  = 7;
my $cur_job = 0;

my $cv = AnyEvent->condvar;
$cv->begin();

for (1..($pool_size < $num_jobs ? $pool_size : $num_jobs)) {
    $cv->begin();
    make_job($cur_job++);
}

$cv->end();

sub make_job {
    my $job = shift;
    $num_jobs--;

    http_get 'http://download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip', sub {
        my ($data, $headers) = @_;
        if ($headers->{Status} =~ /^2/) { 
            print "download [$job] succeeded.\n"; 
        } else { 
            print "download [$job] failed.\n"; 
        }

        if ($num_jobs > 0) {
            make_job($cur_job++);
        }
        else {
            $cv->end();
        }
    };
}

$cv->recv();
```

Comment: This is much simpler than `AnyEvent::Worker`. Nicely done. Do you have any idea what was going wrong with it?

Comment: I think you can't rely on same event loop in the child process. This is not safe

Comment: Oh, thanks. I wasn't even aware `AnyEvent::Worker` created sub-processes. I guess that should have been obvious given the domain socket warnings in the output. :-/

Comment: As a sidenote, if ever needed, then AnyEvent::Fork (and related modules) can create processes where using AnyEvent or other event loops can be used. For this problem the above answer is of course more appropriate.